# XAML's MouseOver Trigger's Enter/Exit Actions loops infinitely when touching the edge of a UI Element

Tags: xaml

I'm trying to create a button in XAML with a mouse over trigger that turns its 0 margin to 0,0,0,5 but recently found a problem when I left the cursor on the edge-most of the button. The start and end actions constantly gets triggered and I end up with a button going up and down infinitely.

Some additional info:

1. I'm using Visual Studio 2017
2. The project is WPF

I think I could fix this this in c# if I applied a boolean requirement for the exit action to run only if the enter action finishes or goes a digit above the default value. I'll do this in the meantime but if you guys have any xaml-specific solution I would very much appreciate it as I wanted to leave the animations to xaml as much as possible.

```
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation 
                                            From="0"
                                            To="0.4"
                                            Duration="0:0:0.2"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Effect.Opacity"/>
                            <ThicknessAnimation 
                                            From="0"
                                            To="0,0,0,5"
                                            Duration="0:0:0.2"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </Trigger.EnterActions>
                <Trigger.ExitActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation 
                                            From="0.4"
                                            To="0"
                                            Duration="0:0:0.2"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Effect.Opacity"/>
                            <ThicknessAnimation 
                                            From="0,0,0,5"
                                            To="0"
                                            Duration="0:0:0.2"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </Trigger.ExitActions>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
```

Comment: Or what if I put it inside a transparent grid that's large enough to hold its default and animated size and have my MouseOver trigger there instead? Might look a bit silly though since if I tried to put my cursor on the bottom-most part of the grid, the button will still float even if the cursor is not directly on top of the bottom, just the grid containing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need additional container and reserved space for shift.

- wrap your animation Border with Transparent Grid
- assign name to border
- move animation triggers to ControlTemplate level
- add extra margin for border, which will be used as free space to shift up
- adjust From/To ThicknessAnimation properties to use reserved margin property
- add Storyboard.TargetName="{Border}" for story board elements (where {Border} is actual border name)

Complete button example

```
<Button Width="100" Height="50">
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <Grid Background="Transparent">
                                <Border x:Name="Border" BorderThickness="5" BorderBrush="Black" Margin="0,5,0,0" Background="Red">
                                    <Border.Style>
                                        <Style TargetType="Border">
                                            <Setter Property="Effect">
                                                <Setter.Value>
                                                    <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0" BlurRadius="8" Color="#FFB0E9EF"/>
                                                </Setter.Value>
                                            </Setter>
                                        </Style>
                                    </Border.Style>
                                </Border>
                            </Grid>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger  Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                    <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                        <BeginStoryboard >
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="0.4" Duration="0:0:0.2" Storyboard.TargetName="Border" 
                                                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Effect.Opacity"/>
                                                <ThicknessAnimation From="0,5,0,0" To="0,0,0,5" Duration="0:0:0.2" Storyboard.TargetName="Border" 
                                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin"/>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </BeginStoryboard>
                                    </Trigger.EnterActions>
                                    <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                        <BeginStoryboard>
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <DoubleAnimation From="0.4" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.2" Storyboard.TargetName="Border" 
                                                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Effect.Opacity"/>
                                                <ThicknessAnimation From="0,0,0,5" To="0,5,0,0" Duration="0:0:0.2" Storyboard.TargetName="Border" 
                                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin"/>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </BeginStoryboard>
                                    </Trigger.ExitActions>
                                </Trigger>

                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
    </Button>
```

Comment: Apologies for the late reply and award as I haven't visited in a while since I've already applied the solution I've mentioned. Nevertheless, this looks like a very clean way of doing it and will be updating my xaml with this code. Thanks for the help.